# Argument error when trying to create a mission

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, argument-error

I have a form for creating new Missions with an Admin account. Each Mission is linked to an account. When I visit admin/missions/new I get an error "ArgumentError in Admin::Missions#new". Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong?

When I checked the rails console a mission id and name does show up, but I guess I'm missing the Admin for the mission.

Here's my Controller

```rb
class Admin::MissionsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def index
    @missions = missions
  end

  def new
    @mission = current_account.missions.new(params[:mission])

    @mission.save

  end

  def create
    render plain: params[:mission].inspect
  end


  def edit
    @mission = missions.find(params[:id])
  end




  private

  def missions 
    @missions ||= current_account.missions
  end
end
```

Here's my form

```rb
<%= form_with [:admin, @mission] do |f| %>
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

I'm expecting the url admin/missions/new to take me to the form, but I I get the argument error wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: may be it is due to `current_account.missions.new(params[:mission])` this, you are calling a method in the new method and it takes parameter, which is blank??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have params yet in the new action as the view (where the form which has to collect the params is) is rendered after the controller code. The object should be created in the **create** action:

```
def create
  current_account.missions.create(params[:mission])
end
```

And the new action should be just:

```
def new
  @mission = current_account.missions.new
end
```

Check the [*Binding a Form to an Object* section of the Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/form_helpers.html).

The form code seems also to be wrong, as `form_with [:admin, @mission] do |f|` is not a valid syntax. It should be:

```
<%= form_with model: [:admin, @mission] do |form| %>
```

Check [`form_with` documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) for more details.

Comment: That worked! Thank you Ana for providing the rails documentation with the answer. This will help me grasp the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally new method is just for creating a new instance and create method is for saving records. Changing to what Ana Maria is suggesting should fix your issue. Thanks.